# How can I get users to select options in the format "at least X MBit/s"?

Tags: selection, labeling

I need a select box to filter a search result.  The user can select: at least 1 MBit/s, at least 100 MBit/s, at least 1 GBit/s, at least 5 GBit/s *or* any.

In fact we have the select already, there the user can select "1+", "100+", "1k+", "5k+" or "*". Above the select is a label reading "capacity (MBit/s)". Pretty obvious thing for very technical people. Non technical people don't understand this and therefore don't even use the feature right now.

Long story short, one improvement would be no unit label above and options reading: "1+ MBit/s", "100+ MBit/s", ..., "Any". But I think it still looks weird! What is the combination of best looking and least confusion? It should appeal to techies and non-techies.

EDIT: and there is a space constraint in width, so "at least 100 MBit/s" would be too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but how about  using a slider which the user can move up and down to determine the minimum value he desires and he can set the maximum value too

[image]

Take this example from iconfinder where I can use the slider to determine the minimum and maximum size of the icon that I want. You could use a slider like this to allow the user to choose between atleast and maximum values.

An alternative approach would be to use a dropdown and show a dynamically updated text box next to it which mentions the speed in kb/s or what ever basic unit you feel users might understand

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGEiat.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  You are right this is not what I am looking for *currently*.  But as the UI evolves I have more time to include more fancy controls and your solutions will be perfect then.

Comment: (The alternative solution is nice too but overkill; it's already possible in the search bar to do advanced searches.)